# override inline css !important

Tags: javascript, css, overriding

how can I override the style "color: red" either with javascript or CSS? I want to make it "2px" instead of "1px" border.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ccccc !important"> 
       Lorem... 
</div>
```

I can NOT add a class, id to the "div". that is not a solution here. I have to override the code above somehow.

**Solution**
Used jquery already loaded on the site. 
Ran:
$( document ).ready(function() { $('table[style*=border]').css('border-width',"4px"); });
https://jsfiddle.net/78oxmgLj/10/

Comment: *"how can I override the style "color: red""* There is no `color: red` style in your question. Separately: Why can't you remove the inline style?

Comment: why I cant remove the inline style: Im injecting css and js into a website via a chrome browser plugin to customize the website. making a theme on top of a theme if that makes sense.. just playing around. (=

Answer (score 2):

With your actual code you cannot do it with CSS (As @T.J. Crowder commented, there is no CSS rule that can *beat* inline with `!important`) but here is a JS solution:

```js
document.querySelector('.box').style.borderWidth="2px";
document.querySelector('.box').style.borderColor="red";

//or
//document.querySelector('.box').style.border="2px solid red";
```

```html
<div class="box" style="border: 1px solid #cccccc!important">
  Lorem...
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

If for some reason you cannot add class you can use [attribute selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/) based on style *(but I don't advice to use this as a generic solution)*

```js
document.querySelector('div[style*=border]').style.borderWidth="2px";
document.querySelector('div[style*=border]').style.borderColor="red";
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #cccccc!important">
  Lorem...
</div>
```

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? It's correct on both points: An `!important` inline rule beats *any* rule applied by a stylesheet, but can be modified by code.

Comment: I cant add a class. 

ps - your post should have not been downvoted )=

Comment: @1xxooxx i added another way, but i don't adivce to use it a lot :) but it will work in your case

Comment: @1xxooxx: There will be *some* way you can select the element, doesn't have to be a class; see the [CSS selector spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) (since `querySelector` uses CSS selectors).

Comment: still not working for some reason. im using JS. is the code below correct? 
<script>
var _min = [{}];   document.querySelector('table[style*=border]').style.borderWidth="0px 0px 0px 0px";</script>

Comment: @1xxooxx it's not correct, why `0px 0px 0px 0px` ? it sould be only one value

Comment: the "0px" was not working, so I google and also found that someone else was using "0px 0px 0px 0px". That one also didnt work.

Comment: @TemaniAfif: `border-width` can be 1, 2, 3, or 4 values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-width Just one value should be sufficient here, of course.

Comment: @1xxooxx: You *might* need `.style.borderWidth = "0px !important"` if there's a CSS `!important` style also applied to the element.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes sure it's correct but not needed (that's what i meant) and he no need to add !imporant, as it will be added automatically by JS ... but now i think his selector is wrong.

Comment: @1xxooxx i see you are applying the style to a table not a div .. can you show me the HTML code to be sure the selector is correct ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif yes im applying it to a table so I changed the code to satisfy what I needed. see here: https://imgur.com/a/ED2g6

Comment: @1xxooxx strage, it should have worked, are you able to create a small jsfiddle.net ? so we can test together

Comment: @1xxooxx i see, first there was a small typo error and second you try to remive from Many table and not only one (this make a big difference) as the code i wrote will select only the first .. so i updated the code in order to create a loop to change all the tables https://jsfiddle.net/78oxmgLj/9/

Comment: @TemaniAfif it works on jsfiddle, but not on the actual page. very weird. what do you think about having js "find and replace"?

Comment: @1xxooxx can i see the page ? maybe using iframe or something like this ?

Comment: @1xxooxx i don't see the JS code in the page , where it's added ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif via my browser with https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/minimalist-for-everything/bmihblnpomgpjkfddepdpdafhhepdbek

Comment: @1xxooxx and are your sure the code is added at then end of the page ?

Comment: added at the beginning of the page automatically https://imgur.com/a/NTWEL

Comment: @1xxooxx ok i see, the code should be added at the end to work. So you can consider adding document ready. Try this Jquery code instead `$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('table[style*=border]').css('border-width',"4px");
});`

Comment: YES YES YES! Brilliant! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is true, there are ways depending on your usecase that you can do here with CSS alone. Even if you cannot override the specific value, you can use a different property to change the original state.

```css
b {
  filter: hue-rotate(250deg); /*blue*/
}

i {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(0.4);
}
```

```html
<b style="color: red !important">Stack</b>
<i style="font-size: 50px !important">Stack</i>
```

In your example, if you need to change 1px important inline border to 2px, you can use outline or box-shadow without blurring:

```css
div:first-child {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid #cccccc !important"> 
       Lorem... 
</div>
<br>
<div style="border: 4px solid #cccccc !important"> 
       Lorem... 
</div>
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using tags that are not standard. You are breaking normal browser rules and forcing the browser to work in a way is not made to. Furthermore, this may affect your SEO.

Comment: Nonetheless, I consider your second example good.